# Is there a way to use just build command instead of ant build while using ant scripts?

Tags: ant, build

I am using Apache Ant scripts for building a web application. I have written some targets in the build.xml file and the script is running fine. I remember using just "build" command to run ant build instead of "ant build". Can anyone tell me how is that achieved? I was a bit curious on this.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built in "build" command. You could create a simple script file called "build" in the same directory that launched the ant build.

Create a text file with this as the contents:

```
ant build
```

In windows save this as a file called `build.bat` then you can just type `build` from the command line to start your build.

On unix or linux, save the file as `build`, then make it executable (with `chmod +x build`). You'll need to type `./build` to get it to run.

I don't think there's a lot of value doing this to replace the simple case of `ant build`, but if you have to regularly run a build that has multiple targets, or need to pass in certain system variables then it could come in useful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your are remembering typing "ant" instead of "ant build" in the past. This is possible to setup. You just need to set default attribute on the root project element in your Ant script to the name of the target you want invoked when an explicit target isn't specified.

For instance...

```
<project name="myproj" default="build">
  ... 
</project>
```